# REGEX Help for a validation rule

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule, regular-expressions

I am trying to write a validation rule using REGEX that will enforce this format `(1-10):(1-10)` in a Text field.

Example: `(2):(5)`

Open parenthesis + # between 1 and 10 + Close parenthesis + colon + Open parenthesis + # between 1 and 10 + Close parenthesis

```
NOT(REGEX( Text_Field__c, needhelpwiththispart )
```

Comment: Have you tried anything, maybe, an online regex editor, such as [this one](https://regex101.com/)?

Comment: I did batt...but I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do something like:

```
NOT(REGEX(Text_Field__c, "\\((10|[1-9])\\):\\((10|[1-9])\\)"))
```

> [Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/00gJxl/1)
>
> **`\((10|[1-9])\):\((10|[1-9])\)`**
>
> - **`\(`** matches the character `(` literally (case sensitive)
> - 1st Capturing Group **`(10|[1-9])`**
>
>   - 1st Alternative **`10`**
>       **`10`** matches the characters `10` literally (case sensitive)
>   - 2nd Alternative **`[1-9]`**
>       Match a single character present in the list below `[1-9]`
>       **`1-9`** a single character in the range between `1` (ASCII 49) and `9` (ASCII 57) (case sensitive)
> - **`\)`** matches the character `)` literally (case sensitive)
> - **`:`** matches the character `:` literally (case sensitive)
> - **`\(`** matches the character `(` literally (case sensitive)
> - 2nd Capturing Group **`(10|[1-9])`**
>
>   - 1st Alternative **`10`**
>       **`10`** matches the characters `10` literally (case sensitive)
>   - 2nd Alternative **`[1-9]`**
>       Match a single character present in the list below `[1-9]`
>       **`1-9`** a single character in the range between `1` (ASCII 49) and `9` (ASCII 57) (case sensitive)
> - **`\)`** matches the character `)` literally (case sensitive)

Comment: Thanks Adrian...that worked...what if I also want to allow 0

Comment: @SafariSteve Just change `[1-9]` to `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
[(]([1-9]|10)[)][:][(]([1-9]|10)[)]
```

In order, it matches:

`[(]` - Literal `(`

`([1-9]|10)` - 1 through 9, or 10

`[)]` - Literal `)`

`[:]` - Literal `:`

The rest is repeated from the above.